# Unable to swap telex and vin on ubuntu 13.10 (ibus error)

Tags: ibus

After installing Ubuntu 13.10, and I chose Vietnam( Unikey ). I only typed by telex mode, but I want use Vni mode. Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Install the ibus-m17n package

```
$ sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n
```

Restart ibus

```
$ ibus restart
```

Go to System Settings > Text Entry, click the plus sign (+) to add a new input source, select "Vietnamese (vni (m17n)) then you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can follow [the steps in this link](http://rmitc.org/2013/07/ibus-bogo-an-ideal-substitutes-of-ibus-unikey-go-tieng-viet-tren-ubuntu/):

Step 1: Install Bogo

Step 2: Use the Text Entry Setting to add GoGo.

(Reboot to ensure everything works well)

Step 3: Enable VNI or Telet as Input Method

Lauch the " BoGo application" and choose VNI or Telet, it is up to you.

Step 4: Enjoy

Some error we faced:
If BoGo is enabled, I can not type any thing into "Search Box" to search.